# How to use a loop to add layers to the map that are not already displayed?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, layer

I'm new to javascript so apologies if this is a super basic question!

So I have an resetMap feature which uses a loop to remove layers from a map, as follows:

function resetMap() {

```
let layers = [Frog1Layer, Frog2Layer, Frog3Layer, Frog4Layer, Frog5Layer, Frog6Layer, Frog7Layer, Frog8Layer,
Frog1Marker, Frog2Marker, Frog3Marker, Frog4Marker, Frog5Marker, Frog6Marker, Frog7Marker, Frog8Marker]


for (let layer of layers) {

if (layer) {

map.removeLayer(layer)
}
}
```

Now I am trying to add an addAllLayers function, using a similar loop. Issue is, I don't really understand what the resetMap loop actually does.

I can see that it loops through the array, and if it has each layer, it removes it. But what does the "for (let layer of layers) {" bit actually mean? And how do I write a similar loop that adds layers?

So far I have this:

function showAllLayers() {

```
let layers = ([Frog1Layer, Frog2Layer, Frog3Layer, Frog4Layer, Frog5Layer, Frog6Layer, Frog7Layer, Frog8Layer,
Frog1Marker, Frog2Marker, Frog3Marker, Frog4Marker, Frog5Marker, Frog6Marker, Frog7Marker, Frog8Marker]);

for (let layer of layers) {

if (layer) {

map.addLayer(layer)
}
}
```

but it doesn't seem right, as it only adds a layer if the layer has previously been added to the map.

Can anyone explain?

Many thanks!

Comment: take out the `if (layer) ` check, just do `map.addLayer(layer)` without a check and see what that does.

Comment: i get an error in the web console which says "t is undefined"

Comment: well, then unfortunately that means that I don't have enough information to help you, because I know nothing about how each of these layers is created.

Comment: :-( thanks anyway. can you tell me what "for (let layer of layers)" means? I can't figure out what's going on bc I don't even understand what my code is doing..

Comment: its a for... of loop. It just loops through the array https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

Comment: When you write `for (let x of y) {}`, you're basically going over an array of items, `y`, and doing something with each element of that array, `x`. `x` becomes a variable only inside the `{}` brackets. `x` takes the value of each element of `y` in order.